# write string on an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift

I'm trying to match between 2 different images using sift,
What i want to do is to write a text (number) on the image.

```
hold on;
cols1 = size(im1,2);
for i = 1:1: size(des1,1)
  if (match(i) > 0)
    line([loc1(i,2) loc2(match(i),2)+cols1], [loc1(i,1) loc2(match(i),1)], 'Color', 'b');
    s = int2str(i);
    text (loc1(1,2), loc2(match(1),2)+cols1,s,...
    'FontSize',14,...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center');  
  end
end

hold off;
```

I'm getting an error Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
at   `text (loc1(1,2), loc2(match(1),2)+cols1,s,...`

I can't figure out what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

`match(1)` in that line may be zero (or at least not an positive integer). I note that you check `match(i)`, but not `match(1)`. Do you mean to use `match(i)`? That is,

```
text (loc1(1,2), loc2(match(i),2)+cols1,s,...
```

Comment: Perhaps you also want to use `loc(i,2)` for the horizontal coordinate?